# bootstrap dropdown menu in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am making a template, but I can't make the dropdown menu working.
When i add a page to the menu it works just fine, but when I add a dropdown menu, it is just standing next to the main menu item.

Here you can see it:
http://www.glazenwasserijnederpel.nl/nijs/

My code for the header:

```
<header>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img class="logo" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Logo hetpannenkoekenhuis"></a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <?php wp_nav_menu ( array('theme_location' => 'primary')); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

My code for the functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary header navigation' );
register_nav_menu( 'secondary', 'Menu navigation' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nav walker in order for bootstrap dropdown menus to work on wordpress. This link will give the code neccessary:[Nav Walker](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-bootstrap-navbar-into-wordpress-theme--wp-33410)